# Sencha Touch (1.1) - Model not updated in localstorage after "successful" save

Tags: model, proxy, save, sencha-touch, local-storage

## My Setup

- Safari 5.1.2 (Macintosh)
- Sencha Touch 1.1

## The Issue

### The process

I have a model and a store. I update a record using the `set(field,value)` method documented here: [API - Set](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.util.Stateful-method-set). After updating fields, I use `save()` method documented here: [API - Save](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-save).

### The Result

The record updates in any lists that are bound to the store and **appears to be saved**, however when I **reload the webpage** the **old values** are displayed. So the record is updated, the store see's the new data, the lists bound to the store refresh their display, but the actual representation of the data in localstorage is never updated. If you use the browser console to find and inspect the item with something like `var record = summaryStore.getAt(4)`, you will find that the `dirty` attribute is false even if the `save()` call has not been made. Also `summaryStore.getUpdatedRecords()` returns an empty set regardless of whether the `save()` method has been called.

### Further documentation

[API - Models](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model)

[API - Stores](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store)

[API - Proxies](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Proxy)

## The Code

### Store

```
var summaryStore = new Ext.data.Store({
model: 'EventSummary',
storeId: 'summaryStore',
sortOnLoad: true,
sorters: [
    {
        property: 'date',
        direction: 'DESC'
    }
],
proxy: {
    type: 'localstorage',
    id  : 'summary-cache'
}
})
```

### Model

```
Ext.regModel('EventSummary', {
fields: [
    {name: 'child', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'date', type: 'date'},
    {name: 'description', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'event_id', type: 'int'}
],
proxy: summaryStore.proxy
})
```

### Example

```
var record = summaryStore.findExact('event_id', 90)
record.date = new Date();
record.description = 'Vitamin K Shot`
record.save()
```

Both *before* and *after* the `record.save()`, the `dirty` flag is false. `summaryStore.getUpdatedRecords()` returns an empty set both *before* and *after* the save. All lists to summary store reflect the change made regardless of whether the record is saved.

### Additional Notes

The store is populated with this call, which follows the declaration of the store and the model. `summaryStore.load()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

The issue can be avoided altogether by properly instantiating your model instances before passing them to the store's `add` method. I was just passing in JSON, which the store accepted, but apparently was causing issues.

**End Update**

The issue can be fixed by making changes in **WebStorageProxy.js**

*Be advised that changing this file does not modify your sencha-touch.js file. You will have to rebuild it or modify it directly*

This code was not working

```
setRecord: function(record, id) {
    if (id) {
        record.setId(id);
    } else {
        id = record.getId();
    }
```

This line in particular `id = record.getId();` for some reason was coming up undefined on objects that had already been added to the store. The solution is to add

```
if (id === undefined) {
    id = record.internalId;
}
```

The final code looks like

```
setRecord: function(record, id) {
    if (id) {
        record.setId(id);
    } else {
        id = record.getId();
        if (id === undefined) {
            id = record.internalId;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The setDirty workaround mentioned above didn't work for me, but I found another workaround for saving records to a WebLocalStorage proxy:

```
record.set('field1', 'abc');
store.proxy.setRecord(record);
```

I'm using 1.1.1.
(And btw for some reason I can't call save(); the exception says I need a url, which is inapplicable to weblocalstorage.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the sync() method on the store to persist the data to localstorage.

Try this code instead of your example above:

```
var record = summaryStore.findExact('event_id', 90)
record.set('date', new Date());
record.set('description', 'Vitamin K Shot`);
record.save();

summaryStore.sync();
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not working in this case. The store actually doesn't recognize the changes `summaryStore.getUpdatedRecords()` returns an empty set.

Comment: After setting the value, try model.setDirty().

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work either. I ended up having to make a source change to the WebStorageProxy object.